# JWT claims issue after Upgraded Identity server 4 to Duneden server

Tags: .net, serialization, jwt, escaping, duende-identity-server

I have recently upgraded the `identity server 4` to `duende Identity server` along with upgrading `.netcore 3` to `.net 6` version and done the Db migration related to `Dunende` as well.

The JWT is working fine and I can get `authorized` fine but the claims check failing, when looking into the `Appclaims` in the `payload` of inside the `JWT`, it looks fine other than then they are also having back spaces (escape character) in it.
I have tried to remove the escape charter using `string.replace("\\","")` but it didnt work.
My major concern is why I am having the back spaces in the first place as it was working fine before the upgrade and if any way I can over come this issue.

`"isEnabled": "True", "AppClaims": "[{\"AppName\":\"TTU\",\"Instance\":\"TTU-dev-solihull\",\"Claims\":[\"StrategyManager-R\",\"StrategyManager-RW\",\"BootMessages-R\",\"BootMessages-RW\",\"SystemLog-R\",\"SystemLog-RW\",\"TimeTable-R\",\"TimeTable-RW\",\"NetworkConfig-R\",\"NetworkConfig-RW\",\"CommandManager-R\",\"CommandManager-RTextCommand\",\"UserManagement-R\",\"UserManagement-RW\",\"SignalPlan-R\",\"SignalPlan-RW\",\"SignalPlan-Admin\",\"CommandBatch-R\",\"CommandBatch-RW\",\"CountDetector-R\",\"AstridProcessor-R\",\"AstridProcessor-RW\",\"Access-VPN-Equipment\",\"RoleManagement-R\",\"RoleManagement-RW\",\"FaultManagement-RW\",\"FaultManagement-R\",\"NET:1-569-1\"]},{\"AppName\":\"TTU\",\"Instance\":\"TTU-dev-stoke\",\"Claims\":[\"StrategyManager-R\",\"StrategyManager-RW\",\"BootMessages-R\",\"BootMessages-RW\",\"SystemLog-R\",\"SystemLog-RW\",\"TimeTable-R\",\"TimeTable-RW\",\"NetworkConfig-R\",\"NetworkConfig-RW\",\"CommandManager-R\",\"CommandManager-RNonPersitent\",\"CommandManager-RPersitent\",\"CommandManager-RTextCommand\",\"UserManagement-R\",\"UserManagement-RW\",\"SignalPlan-R\",\"SignalPlan-RW\",\"SignalPlan-Admin\",\"CommandBatch-R\",\"CommandBatch-RW\",\"CountDetector-R\",\"AstridProcessor-R\",\"AstridProcessor-RW\",\"Access-VPN-Equipment\",\"RoleManagement-R\",\"RoleManagement-RW\",\"NET:8-1-1\"]},{\"AppName\":\"TTU\",\"Instance\":\"TTU-dev-radcliffe\",\"Claims\":[\"StrategyManager-R\",\"StrategyManager-RW\",\"BootMessages-R\",\"BootMessages-RW\",\"SystemLog-R\",\"SystemLog-RW\",\"TimeTable-R\",\"TimeTable-RW\",\"NetworkConfig-R\",\"NetworkConfig-RW\",\"CommandManager-R\",\"CommandManager-RNonPersitent\",\"CommandManager-RPersitent\",\"CommandManager-RTextCommand\",\"UserManagement-R\",\"UserManagement-RW\",\"SignalPlan-R\",\"SignalPlan-RW\",\"SignalPlan-Admin\",\"CommandBatch-R\",\"CommandBatch-RW\",\"CountDetector-R\",\"AstridProcessor-R\",\"AstridProcessor-RW\",\"Access-VPN-Equipment\",\"RoleManagement-R\",\"RoleManagement-RW\",\"FaultManagement-RW\",\"FaultManagement-R\",\"NET:6-1-1\"]},{\"AppName\":\"TTU\",\"Instance\":\"TTU-luton-masterdev\",\"Claims\":[\"StrategyManager-R\",\"StrategyManager-RW\",\"BootMessages-R\",\"BootMessages-RW\",\"SystemLog-R\",\"SystemLog-RW\",\"TimeTable-R\",\"TimeTable-RW\",\"NetworkConfig-R\",\"NetworkConfig-RW\",\"CommandManager-R\",\"CommandManager-RNonPersitent\",\"CommandManager-RPersitent\",\"CommandManager-RTextCommand\",\"UserManagement-R\",\"UserManagement-RW\",\"SignalPlan-R\",\"SignalPlan-RW\",\"SignalPlan-Admin\",\"CommandBatch-R\",\"CommandBatch-RW\",\"CountDetector-R\",\"AstridProcessor-R\",\"AstridProcessor-RW\",\"Access-VPN-Equipment\",\"RoleManagement-R\",\"RoleManagement-RW\",\"FaultManagement-RW\",\"FaultManagement-R\",\"NET:16-1-1\"]},{\"AppName\":\"TTU\",\"Instance\":\"TTU-dev-swarco\",\"Claims\":[\"AstridProcessor-R\",\"CommandBatch-R\",\"CommandManager-R\",\"CountDetector-R\",\"NET:14-1-1\",\"NetworkConfig-R\",\"BootMessages-R\",\"SignalPlan-R\",\"StrategyManager-R\",\"SystemLog-R\",\"TimeTable-R\",\"UserManagement-R\"]},{\"AppName\":\"TTU\",\"Instance\":\"TTU-ukaea-masterdev\",\"Claims\":[\"AstridProcessor-R\",\"CommandBatch-R\",\"CommandManager-R\",\"CountDetector-R\",\"NET:15-1-1\",\"NetworkConfig-R\",\"BootMessages-R\",\"SignalPlan-R\",\"StrategyManager-R\",\"SystemLog-R\",\"TimeTable-R\",\"UserManagement-R\"]},{\"AppName\":\"TTU\",\"Instance\":\"TTU-dev-clonedwoolwich\",\"Claims\":[\"AstridProcessor-R\",\"CommandBatch-R\",\"CommandManager-R\",\"CountDetector-R\",\"NET:1-7-1\",\"NetworkConfig-R\",\"BootMessages-R\",\"SignalPlan-R\",\"StrategyManager-R\",\"SystemLog-R\",\"TimeTable-R\",\"UserManagement-R\"]},{\"AppName\":\"TTU\",\"Instance\":\"TTU-dev-portsmouth\",\"Claims\":[\"AstridProcessor-R\",\"CommandBatch-R\",\"CommandManager-R\",\"CountDetector-R\",\"NET:12-1-1\",\"NetworkConfig-R\",\"BootMessages-R\",\"SignalPlan-R\",\"StrategyManager-R\",\"SystemLog-R\",\"TimeTable-R\",\"UserManagement-R\"]},{\"AppName\":\"TTU\",\"Instance\":\"TTU-dev-paris\",\"Claims\":[\"AstridProcessor-R\",\"CommandBatch-R\",\"CommandManager-R\",\"CommandManager-RPersitent\",\"CountDetector-R\",\"NET:13-1-1\",\"NetworkConfig-R\",\"BootMessages-R\",\"SignalPlan-R\",\"StrategyManager-R\",\"SystemLog-R\",\"TimeTable-R\",\"UserManagement-R\"]},{\"AppName\":\"TTU\",\"Instance\":\"TTU-dev-bristol\",\"Claims\":[\"AstridProcessor-R\",\"CommandBatch-R\",\"CommandManager-R\",\"CountDetector-R\",\"NET:9-1-1\",\"NetworkConfig-R\",\"BootMessages-R\",\"SignalPlan-R\",\"StrategyManager-R\",\"SystemLog-R\",\"TimeTable-R\",\"UserManagement-R\"]},{\"AppName\":\"TTU\",\"Instance\":\"TTU-solihull-masterdev\",\"Claims\":[\"AstridProcessor-R\",\"CommandBatch-R\",\"CommandManager-R\",\"CountDetector-R\",\"NET:1-569-1\",\"NetworkConfig-R\",\"BootMessages-R\",\"SignalPlan-R\",\"StrategyManager-R\",\"SystemLog-R\",\"TimeTable-R\",\"UserManagement-R\"]}]"`

-Code snipet below where it is getting added as a claim `(JsonSerializer.Serialize(appClaims))` this code hasnt been changed and before the upgrade the claims were coming without the `\`, it shouldnt include `\` as it is for the escape charater for `"`in the strings.

```
          AppClaim[] appClaims;

        // convert the user permission to appClaim format to add as a claim.
        // For TTC specific users: in case role added for user, selects claims associated with the role from UserRoleClaims table
        // else selects the claims of the user directly from user permissions table
        appClaims = userPermissions.ToList().Select(async x => new AppClaim
        {
            Claims = x.AppRoleId != null ? await GetRoleClaims(x.AppRoleId, x.AppClaims) : x.Claims.Split(sepChar),
            AppName = x.AppName,
            Instance = x.Name
        }).Select(x => x.Result).ToArray<AppClaim>();

        claims.Add(new Claim(AppClaims, JsonSerializer.Serialize(appClaims), JsonClaimValueTypes.JsonArray));
        context.IssuedClaims = claims;
```

Comment: I think its better to add the claims, one by one (with the same claim name) than trying to serialize it.

Comment: So claims are getting added but JWT having claims with the backslash as well "\", the method I am working on with is `GetProfileDataAsync` , it looks like when I add the claims to `context.IssuedClaims` it gets messed up somehow, although haven't done any change other than moving from identity server 4 to Duneden server

Comment: can you not just add the  appClaims, one by one, using claims.Add, so you can avoid the extra serialization? Also, it could be that they move from Newtonsoft.JSON to the more performant built in JSON Serializer and it behaves lightly different? In general I would not serialize data into a claim, that to me is a code smell.